# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object using Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have just gotten into using premade statements to help with SQL protections.
My script checks to see if the User exists in the Users table and if it does already exist it runs:

```
$stmt = $Con->prepare("UPDATE `HA00`.`Users` SET `Unix` = ?,`4690` = ?,`LastIP` = ?,`LastLogin` = CURRENT_TIME( ) WHERE `Users`.`User` = ?;");

$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$PUnix,$P46,$IP,$PAD);
$PAD = $AD;
$PUnix = $Unix;
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$P46 = $CTR;
$stmt->execute();
```

If the user doesn't exist theirs is a nearly identical Insert SQL Query that works fine. I am positive I am missing something simple. I have checked the other pages but I am not finding the issue.

Edit:

"var_dump($stmt);" shows bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

It cant see parameters $PUnix,$P46,$IP,$PAD.

Try putting $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$PUnix,$P46,$IP,$PAD); below those variables.

Comment: bind_param is one of the few things can can be declared before variables php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php example 1

Comment: try debugging $stmt and see if there's error in there. Might have problem with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try use $stmt->bindValue instead. It should work.